# Can I delete warnings in openshift origin?

Tags: warnings, openshift-origin

Don't get me wrong. I like the warnings, but it just don't have to be there all the time when I execute `oc status -v`.

When I restart the master, router and registry also get restarted and there would be some warning message:

`Warnings:
  * container "registry" in pod/docker-registry-1-cena8 has restarted 3 times
  * container "router" in pod/router-1-lv4vn has restarted 4 times`

Can they be cleared after reviewed?

Answer (score 0):

Those probably should not show up at a low level like that - please open a bug report for that.